# How to ignore twisted response body

Tags: python, twisted

There is an example here how to process the body of a HTTP request:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/web/howto/client.html#auto4

The description here say that once a GET request is made then have to read the body or the connection will remain open:

> An important thing to keep in mind is that the body will only be read
>   from the connection after Response.deliverBody is called. This also
>   means that the connection will remain open until this is done (and the
>   body read). So, in general, any response with a body must have that
>   body read using deliverBody. If the application is not interested in
>   the body, it should issue a HEAD request or use a protocol which
>   immediately calls stopProducing on its transport.

However if the headers indicate an error then there is no need to read the body. In this case how can the body be ignored without leaving the connection open?

Comment: I don't use Twisted, but seems like that you're looking for a `HEAD` request... If the headers of a `HEAD` request are okay, you could just issue the same request with `GET`. :)

Comment: Quoting from the question, "use a protocol which immediately calls stopProducing on its transport."

Comment: @Paulo: as mentioned I have already made a GET request and now found the content is invalid

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ignore what the body is, it is being sent by the remote web server.  If you don't read it, it won't make the web server stop sending it (up to the TCP buffering effects).

You have 3 options:

1. Use `HEAD` request.
2. Read and discard the body.
3. Instead of using `twisted.web`, write your own protocol to connect to the HTTP port of remote server, make a GET request and call `loseConnection()` after reading the headers (I highly recommend against this choice).  Be advised that even if you call `loseConnection()`, there is high likelihood that the server has already sent the response back to you, and it is sitting waiting in your OS's networking buffers.  Only in the case where this is a long polling connection (like *Comet*) does it make sense to interrupt an HTTP connection before reading the full response.

You may also be able to hack `twisted.web`'s transport and remove the producer (in which case `loseConnection()` will work, I recommend reading `twisted.web` code if you want to go this route.

Comment: already made a GET request so (1) is not practical. And I am doing (3) at present but am after a proper approach. I was hoping for something like (2) but the docs say "The loseConnection call will close the connection only when all the data has been written by Twisted out to the operating system"

Comment: @hoju: Yes, `loseConnection` will write what's left in write buffers, but IIRC, it will not read.

Comment: and then connection will be closed? Is this documented?

Comment: @hoju: Normally yes, but in this case no: if there is a producer it won't be closed (so 2 is not an option): http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html#loseConnection

Comment: OK, not keen on hacking my own transport so will keep reading the errors bodies